# IIS 8.0 Second Website on port 81 not visible publicly

Tags: port, connection, website, iis-8

I have been given a VM in Windows Azure with Windows Server 2008 R2/ IIS 8.0 running. It has a default website. Now I wanted to create a dev version of that site at some other port, say 81. I added that application and added inbound rule in the firewall for tcp port 81.

Now I can browse the site on that machine using `http://localhost:81`, but externally I am unable to browse or connect. For the site I used binding to

> http - Any unassigned IP - Port 81 - (hostname left blank)

Here is the fiddler response

> [Fiddler] The connection to 'originaldomainname' failed. 
>   Error: TimedOut (0x274c). 
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond XXX.XX.XXX.XX:81

What can I do to troubleshoot the connection. Is the ISP blocking that port's traffic? Originally I tried to do that on port 8080 but that had the same problem

**Edit**
When I do `netstat -ano | find ":81"` I get this

> TCP    0.0.0.0:81          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
>    TCP    [::]:81             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4

How can I make an entry here? with the public ip as foreign address and private ip as local one.

Comment: Check your windows firewall, maybe it blocking connection from outside, but not from `localhost`

Comment: that is actually I want to ask. How can I check it?

Comment: I tried adding a rule to allow outbound traffic for remote port 81. But it didn't affect anything

Comment: Try open your port 81 for inbound and outbound connection.

Comment: That has not changed anything, how can I diagnose where is the problem in connection. I guess my IIS and VM have the correct settings

Comment: disable the firewall and see if that solves it. If yes, your problem is firewall related, of not, it's not

Comment: that didn't help either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things you have to do for this to work on a VM on Azure.

### Windows Firewall

Make sure you have a firewall rule that allows connection over TCP to port 81. It should look like this

[image]

### Azure Firewall

In Azure portal, go to your VM. Then click on the endpoints tab and add a rule for port 81 as well

it should look like this

[image]

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about the azure management portal, nor do I have access to it, but that would certainly fix the problem. Thank you